# CRM 2011 Navigation Items in Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How to collapse/expand navigation items in form? There is a function setDisplayState but that is for Tabs and not for navigation items.

How can navigation items be collapsed/expand using javascript for crm 2011??

Comment: Issue resolved. You can add the following function on onload of form: 
function hideNavigation()
{
 var nodeList = document.getElementById('crmFormNavSubareas').childNodes;
 for(var i=0; i<nodeList.length; i++){
  if(nodeList[i] != null && nodeList[i].firstChild != null)
   nodeList[i].firstChild.click();
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

The `Xrm` object allows for [interacting with navigation items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328481.aspx), but not with the navigation tabs themselves, so you'll have to use unsupported methods (which may/may not be entirely broken or otherwise made irrelevant in the next version of Dynamics CRM).

Below is an example that checks the collapsed state of each navigation tab and collapses them appropriately.

```js
function SetCollapsedState(navigationName, makeCollapsed) {
    var navItems = document.getElementById("crmFormNavSubareas");
    for (i = 0; i < navItems.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var navItem = navItems.childNodes.item(i);
        var navChild = navItem.firstChild.firstChild;
        var navName = navChild.attributes.getNamedItem("alt").nodeValue;
        if (navName.indexOf(navigationName) === 0) {

            // The "alt" property changes to read "Collapsed" or "Expanded" when 
            // the navigation tab is clicked; this is how I imagine the internal
            // CRM js checks the collapsed state of each tab.

            if ((makeCollapsed === true && navName.indexOf("Expanded") > 0)
                 || (makeCollapsed === false && navName.indexOf("Collapsed") > 0)) {
                navItem.firstChild.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Your answer included as a comment to your question (which, by the way, should probably be made into an actual answer) addresses your question similarly, but I decided to post anyway to include a more comprehensive function as well as mentioning what exactly the `Xrm` object handles/doesn't handle.